# Calculating relative score by number of votes

Tags: math, relationship, rating

Consider that 3 different game/movies got

A: 9.1 in 8000 votes and another got

B: 9.3 in 500 votes, and yet another got

C: 9.5 in 60 votes

What is the best formula to normalize them for comparison. i.e I want to predict what could be the rating of C & B if 8000 votes were cast for them so as to compare with A.

Is there an online calculator for the same? Also I don't have access as how each individual rating them.

Comment: This question might belong on the [Math Stack Exchange site](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Are these average values? If so, then they are already normalized. What more do you want to do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about qualitative statistical methodology, not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply calculate proportion of good votes,

[image]

but it's better to add a correction for total number of votes given.

One way to correct is to add "dummy" bad votes (e.g. 20), so

[image]

Items with a large number of votes see their *modified* percentage alters very little from their *real* percentage, but items with relatively few votes will see their *modified* percentage move considerably *toward low values*.

This is known as "**Bayesian averaging**".
In effect, the item with many votes will rank higher than items with the same percentage but fewer votes.

Answer (score 0):

They are *averages*, and thus are already "normalized".  Unless you have some reason to expect that adding another 7,500 votes to B would change the average, then the number of votes cast does not change the average rating.

If you had some other data such as "ratings drop by 10% after the first X votes" then you *could* possibly extrapolate, but as it is there's no reason to expect that the average would change with more votes.

Comment: It's just the average and he wants to take it a step further and make the number of votes play a bigger role in affecting the total score. I have the same question but can't seem to find a good way to do it. I have two data points

X: Number of Games Played (lowest: 1 highest: 1000)

Y: Average of game scores[sum of game scores / num of games played] (lowest: 4 highest: 6.5)

I don't have record of the individual game scores, I only have the average.

How can i generate a score based on these two variables, in a sense that when [x=1,y=6.5] is worse[has a lower score] than [x=5, y=5.5]